# ionic cordova run android --prod events not working properly

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2, aot

I have installed ion2-calendar  in my ionic application using `npm install ion2-calendar moment --save` and i have made some changes on its files located in `node_modules/ion2-calendar/dist/components/month.component.js`, i have added `(panEnd)` and `(panStart)` in its dates.it is working good using `ionic serve` and `ionic cordova run android`.but the events are not working when we make build usinng --prod option like

```
ionic cordova run android --prod
```

the build was successfull and we can run the app on mobile,but the added event does not works.is there anything we need to do to add this changees in production build?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

use this and please add logs to your question what error is getting generated by NODE servers on backend for your production build on your android devices

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation but I solved this doing this step and rebuilding the project for production.

try production  build commands 
after removing local page module file (i.e login.module.ts) of each of your page!

I mean do this 
[image]

To

[image]

NOTE!! if that does not work for your do post your logs by testing your device logs using

CHROME DEV tools. you can inspect device logs there using

```
chrome://inspect/#devices
```

make sure you are using ADB drivers for your android on your machine!

you won't require this for IOS though you can directly check your log commands in XCODE Console!

Comment: I have no modules for my page

Comment: @Rizwan When possible comments should not be given as answers :)

Comment: @AnoopM thnx I'll keep that in mind ! I updated the answer

Comment: @Rizwanatta I no page modules,which event you have corrected using this method?

Comment: I had the build issue ! too while I was using native calendar and time pickers instead of ionic's own .. I ran into this error mine was solved thnx to CHROME Dev tools! please add your logs using those in your question so I could see what's going on when app events are called after production build @Shin

Comment: @Rizwanatta There is no build error,the event i have added on the specified file is not working if i use --prod

Comment: that's what I am saying too! I know there is no error in the build on first place but when you test the application on device some of the functions don't work especially in the case of building for prod.   
dev tools will tell you what is really going on in the app on run time by posting logs in your browser! so that would be a way to know